# Current date/time field not populating correctly in LiveCycle ES2

Tags: livecycle, livecycle-designer

What I need the field to do is whenever the form is first opened, I need the field to be populated with the current time/date. If I add a ***"Date/Time Field"***, change the ***"Value"*** to ***"Calculated - Read Only"*** and change the ***"Data Format"*** in the ***"Binding"*** tab to ***"Date and Time"***, it doesn't show anything when I preview the PDF. Same goes for if I add a ***"Current Date"*** item and change the ***"Data Format"*** in the ***"Binding"*** tab to ***"Date and Time"***. Will the supplied objects not do this by default? DO I need to use a FormCalc or Javascript script to make it work? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put this in the docReady event of a field I want to populate the date automatically.

```
var today = new Date();
this.rawValue = parseInt(today.getMonth()+1)+"/"+today.getDate()+"/"+today.getFullYear();
```